# How to get array of data members from array of objects in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, class, mapping

Imagine that I have an array of "person" objects:

```
#include <iostream>
class person{
public:
   int age;
   std::string name;
};
```

Is it possible to get an array of the same size with the age (or the name) of each person? I know how to do it with a loop but I hoped there was some kind of "map" that could get me the same in one line.

Comment: [`std::transform`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) could be used. Not sure if that is not too overwhelming though.

Comment: There will be a loop whether you are the one to write it or not.

Comment: With [range-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3): `persons | ranges::view::transform(&Person::age)`.

Comment: @AndyG That is a terrible reason to write a loop. Even though most algorithms like `std::copy` and `std::transform` are just simple loops they improve readability dramatically. Every time you can get away with not manually writing a loop is a win.

Comment: @nwp: I agree. OP said they wanted to avoid a loop, but I was trying to say it's ultimately unavoidable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how it can be done with [`std::transform`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform), [`std::back_inserter`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter), and a lambda:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

struct person{
   int age;
   std::string name;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<person> pp = {{16, "Bob"},{32, "Alice"}};
    std::vector<int> ages;
    std::transform(
        pp.begin(), 
        pp.end(), 
        std::back_inserter(ages),
        [](const person& p) -> int { return p.age; });
    for(auto v: ages)
        std::cout << v << " ";
}
```

Output:

```
16 32
```

<kbd>[**Live demo**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/09wSq2Ny20ti9c7L)</kbd>

**UPDATE:** to avoid unnecessary re-allocations you can call `ages.reserve(pp.size())` before a call of `std::transform`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could, using `transform` both for legacy arrays and for standard containers such as `std::vector`.

**Using legacy arrays**

```
person persons[2] = { { 20, "name1" }, { 21, "name2" } };
for (auto & person : persons)
    cout << person.age << " " << person.name << endl;

decltype(person::age) ages[sizeof(persons)/sizeof(persons[0])];
std::transform(std::begin(persons), std::end(persons), std::begin(ages), [](person & p) -> decltype(person::age) { return p.age; });
for (auto & age : ages)
    cout << age << endl;
```

**Using `std::vector`**

```
std::vector<person> persons = { { 20, "name1" }, { 21, "name2" } };
for (auto & person : persons)
    cout << person.age << " " << person.name << endl;

std::vector<decltype(person::age)> ages(persons.size());
std::transform(persons.begin(), persons.end(), ages.begin(), [](person & p) -> decltype(person::age) { return p.age; });
for (auto & age : ages)
    cout << age << endl;
```

This dynamically extracts the ages of all the persons in the original container.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of generality I assume with array you mean a dynamically sized array, then the full example would be:

```
#include <string>
struct person {
   int age;
   std::string name;
};

std::vector<int> getAge(std::vector<person> p) { 
   std::vector<int> result;
   result.reserve(p.size());
   for (auto& e : p) result.push_back(e.age);
   return result;
}
```

or you using `std::transform` that would be

```
#include <algorithm>
int  main() {
    std::vector<person> foo(10);
    std::vector<int>    ages(10);
    std::transform(foo.begin(),foo.end(),ages.begin(),[](person& p){return p.age;});
}
```

In any case, there is no magic way to get an array of members from an array of instances. There must be a loop somewhere (transform just does a very good job at hiding that loop from you).

Comment: @Ron yes, fixed. And only now i discovered OP is asking for a one-liner. However, whether one writes a function or uses an algorithm it can be done in one line and directly visible or not there must be a loop